# Specify the order and priority of LocationMatch directives from different Apache conf files

Tags: apache2, configuration

I have custom modules loaded in Apache HTTP Server that handles different URL's i.e each module handles a specific URL depending upon the `LocationMatch` directive defined in each of these modules.

The problem is sometimes a particular URL is matched by 2 modules and the first module to handle that URL here is not the one that is supposed to handle. To solve this I tried to rename the conf. file to the format for eg.

- `00-First-Module.conf`
- `01-Second-Module.conf`

But still it seems to be failing and the URL is handled by `01-Second-Module` which in fact should be handled by `00-First-Module`.

Am I missing something? Does it require any other setting to be done?

Note: It works if `01-Second-Module` is disabled.

Comment: Would help if you tell us a bit more about the custom modules but I guess you could look at Apache (Hooks) method by calling the second module once the first module has been launched.

Comment: well we used [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html) to develop our own modules for apache2. Do you mean by [Controlling hook calling order](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/hooks.html#hooking-order) ?